# Have Text stacked above an element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to acheive something similar to this

```
[ sometext ]     [ someothertext]
 actualtext         actualtext2
```

but I am only getting something like

```
som[etext    ]        someoth[ertext        ]
          actualtext                 actualtext2
```

where [] denote an image that is placed in the background. semantically, I want/need to put the stacked elements together e.g.

```
<li class="software1">
            <div class="overlay">
                -soft1
            </div>
            20
        </li>
```

where the overlay element is supposed to be the text above the actual text that is in front of the lis background.

I build a small jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A3VRd/3/ displaying the issue

What I want to achieve is to have the text above actually above the "normal" text and not just elevated but as if it was next to it.

Comment: What does this mean: "text above actually above the "normal" text and not just elevated but as if it was next to it"?  I don't understand what the issue is or what you're trying to accomplish or overcome.

Comment: I added a clarification to my question (I am getting something like...). Does it help to understand? Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post pictures, so I cannot add a more graphical explanation of my issue.

Comment: So you are searching for 2 sentences under each other, the first with a background image and both have to be semantically wrapped by an parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are many ways to do this.  Assuming that you don't want to use background-repeat (because you currently have it set for none) then you need to give the same width to your list elements as the background image you plan to use.

This is similar markup to yours but I have applied the class with the background image to the element contain the "overlay" text.  I also used a span tag because it felt more natural to me, but a div inside of an li is valid, so you can use it if you prefer.

**HTML:**

```
<aside class="compatibility">
    <ul>
        <li> <span class="software1">Here's some Text</span>20</li>
        <li> <span class="software1">Some Other Text</span>20</li>
        <li> <span class="software1">Text of Another One </span>20</li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

**CSS:**

```
aside.compatibility ul {
    margin-top: 64px;
    list-style-type:none;
    position: relative;
}
aside.compatibility li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:64px;
    margin-right:20px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
aside.compatibility .software1 {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x50");
}
aside.compatibility li span {
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you jme11, this helped me a lot. I need the background to be on the li, because not all elements will have this text above, but I managed to change your suggestion to fit my needs!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to given the background-repeat property. Update your CSS like below.

```
aside.compatibility .software1 {
        background-image: url("http://placehold.it/32x32");
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/A3VRd/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Please check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/raj/qCVD8/)

you may need to use z-index css property i guess.

```
        .overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    padding: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    visibility: visible;
    }
    .actual {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #00FFB8;
    padding: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
```